# Include HTML label in property in struts2

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

In the Action is generated HTML code to compare two texts certain letters, letter by letter, being green if they are equal and red if they are different.
JSP:

```
<s:property value="txt"/>
```

Now, JSP displays:

```
El ot<span style="color:green">r</span>o
d<span style="color:red">i</span>a 
f<span style="color:green">u</span>imos a 
na<span style="color:red">_</span>egar en un 
<span style="color:green">y</span>ate.
```

JSP displays the HTML code (just as in the previous example) instead of displaying the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property tag's `escapeHtml` attribute to `false`:

```
<s:property value="txt" escapeHtml="false" />
```

See the [property tag documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/property.html).

Comment: Before writing the question I read property tag documentation but the following error happened:
EscapeHtml attribute is invalid according to the specified TLD


I tried with escape tag (deprecated) and runs...

Comment: +1 to question because this happened to me too. `escapeHtml` never worked, `escape` still do (if I remember well)... any clue @Dave ? :|

Comment: @AndreaLigios I think the different escape attributes were introduced in different versions.

Comment: @user2213180 Then you're using an older version, that's one reason it's good to provide diagnostic information in your questions.